# Deriving formula from geometric relations

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

If we know that [image]

and we have this triangle

[image]

Then how can we derive this relation? [image]

($\alpha$ and $\beta$ are assumed to be small, so that $\tan(\alpha) \approx \alpha$ and $\tan(\beta) \approx \beta$). We also know that $\theta = \alpha + \beta$, so

$$\alpha \approx \frac{4GM}{c^2b}-\tan(\beta)=\frac{4GM}{c^2b}-\frac{b}{D}$$

Also, $b=d\tan(\alpha)=D\tan(\beta)$. But what next? Where is the square root coming from?

Answer (score 2):

$$\tan \alpha=\frac{b}{d} \text{ and } \tan \beta=\frac{b}{D}$$

so,

$$\frac{D/d}{D+d}=\frac{1}{b}\frac{\tan \alpha/\tan \beta}{\frac{1}{\tan \alpha}+\frac{1}{\tan \beta}}=\frac{1}{b}\frac{\tan^2 \alpha}{\tan \alpha+\tan \beta}$$

and,

$$\frac{4GM}{c^2}\frac{D/d}{D+d}=\theta\cdot b\cdot \frac{1}{b}\frac{\tan^2 \alpha}{\tan \alpha+\tan \beta}=\frac{\theta\cdot\tan^2 \alpha}{\tan \alpha+\tan \beta} \quad (*)$$

Using that $\tan\alpha \approx \alpha$ and $\tan\beta \approx \beta$ we get

$$\frac{\theta}{\tan \alpha+\tan \beta}\approx \frac{\theta}{ \alpha+ \beta}=1$$

and backing to $(*)$ we get

$$\alpha^2=\frac{4GM}{c^2}\frac{D/d}{D+d}\to \alpha=\sqrt{\frac{4GM}{c^2}\frac{D/d}{D+d}}$$

Comment: This is a nice solution, but you're going backwards - from the already derived expression. I was trying to derive it by going forward from what was given, and that's the one I'd really be interested in seeing.

Comment: @sequence: you can go backward in my solution and get a forward solution.

Comment: Not quite. The process would look too "artificial". That is, lacking some motivation, like having expressions popping out of nowhere. @Arnaldo

Answer (score 0):

I have found another solution following your idea. Take your last expression:

$$\alpha =\frac{4GM}{c^2b}-\frac{b}{D}$$

Now use that $b=d\tan \alpha\approx d\alpha$:

$$\alpha =\frac{4GM}{c^2d\alpha}-\frac{d\alpha}{D}\to \alpha^2=\frac{4GM}{c^2d}-\frac{d\alpha^2}{D}\\
\alpha^2+\frac{d\alpha^2}{D}=\frac{4GM}{c^2d}\to \alpha^2 \left(1+\frac{d}{D}\right)=\frac{4GM}{c^2d}\\
\alpha ^2=\frac{4GM}{c^2d}\cdot \frac{D}{d+D}\to \alpha =\sqrt{\frac{4GM}{c^2d}\cdot \frac{D}{d+D}}\to\\
\alpha =\sqrt{\frac{4GM}{c^2}\cdot \frac{D/d}{d+D}}$$

Comment: @sequence: I think that is the solution that you are looking for.